# joinLeft and get newest row from duplicate rows of right column

Tags: magento-1.9

My database is as follow:

```
________________________________________________________________
|                        |                                      |
| sales_flat_order       |       custom_payment                 |  
|________________________|______________________________________|
| id    customer         |       id     order_id    date        |
| 1       John           |       1         1        2016-1-1    |
| 2       Peter          |       2         1        2016-2-3    |
| 3       Sam            |       3         2        2016-2-5    |
| 4       Liam           |       4         4        2016-2-5    |
|________________________|______________________________________|
```

**Now, I want the result like this:**

```
id     customer       custom_payment_date
1      John           2016-2-3
2      Peter          2016-2-5
3      Sam            [empty] // no payment value exist for this
4      Liam           2016-2-5
```

My code is:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
$collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('custom_payment'=> $collection->getTable('module/model')),
            'main_table.entity_id = custom_payment.order_id'
        )
        ->group('main_table.entity_id')
        //->order('custom_payment.created_date', 'DESC') //this is not working either
        ;
```

This gives me result but it doesn't gives me newest row from `custom_payment` table, it always selects first one (oldest).

eg:

```
id     customer       custom_payment_date
1      John           2016-1-1 ------//selects first one (oldest)
2      Peter          2016-2-5
3      Sam            [empty] // no payment value exist for this
4      Liam           2016-2-5
```

How can I achieve this? Please suggest.

Comment: Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql

Comment: Thanks for info, I think I have to use `joinLeft`, see my update and also would like to achieve magento way if possible.